# checkbox takes 2 click to take changes because of on change event fired from an input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table that has an input box and a checkbox. Both input box and the check box has **on change** event handler:

[image]

```
 $('#myTable').on('change','.qty',function(){
    console.log(`CHANGE FIRED FROM THE INPUT BOX CHANGE EVENT`)
    //Other code
 
 })

 $('#myTable').on('change','.myCheckbox',function(){
    console.log(`CHANGE FIRED FROM THE CHECKBOX CHANGE EVENT`)
    //Other code
    
 })
```

Now, if I go ahead and click the checkbox without making any changes to the input box the checkbox gets a checkmark  immediately without any issues.

However, if I make changes to the input box, and then click the checkbox (i.e I do not click anywhere within the dom before I click the checkbox after changing the input box), the checkbox does not take the click and does nothing. At this point, I see the console message saying:

> CHANGE FIRED FROM THE INPUT BOX CHANGE EVENT

but I do not get any message from the checkbox check event. If I press the checkbox the second time then it shows the checkmark. I understand that the change event only fires when I make changes and get out of that input box, but why does its change event prevent the checkbox from being checked?

At first I thought that this must be an event propagation issue and I must be stopping event to propagate somewhere. So I added a breakpoint on the console.log line inside the qty change event, fired the change by adding something to input and clicking the checkbox, and checked the call stack. There is no function that runs before it that prevents the checkbox from being checked.

Is this a regular behavior of javascript? If not, I am completely baffled. Can someone help me pointing towards what might be the issue?

Comment: What's in your other code? Does it call `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: why don't you make an onChange on the .qty/.myCheckbox instead of #myTable?

Comment: @DavidGrosh If he's adding rows dynamically, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: It never calls event.stopPropagation(). I am adding the rows dynamically so I have to do it this way